# How to get the id of an instance of a widget by name in php wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, shortcode

I would like to know how to get the ID of a specific instance of a widget using PHP in WordPress. Let's say I have a slider made with smartSlider3. I need to find its ID using its name as a term for the query.

I want to use the ID - if found - to place the slider into a specific post that has same name as slug using a shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

Is the slider a post in a custom post type? If it is, you could query that custom post type using the name of the post which would be the name of the slider. You would then be able to access the post ID of the slider.